# Prove that $P(X=Y)=1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

$\mathcal F$ is a sigma algebra. $X,Y$ are integrable rv. $Y=E[X|\mathcal F]$. $X,Y$ has the same distribution.

1. Prove that if $X$ is square integrable, then $X=Y$ a.s.
2. Prove that for any real $a<b$, we have $\min(\max(X,a),b)=\min(\max(Y,a),b)$ and $X=Y$ a.s.

---

Ok, it is obvious that $Y$ is constant. Let $Y=c$. Since $X,Y$ have the same distribution, $X$ is almost surely constant?

Since $X=c$ a.s. , we have $X=Y$ a.s.

How do we use the condition "square integrable"?

For 2, $\min(\max(X,a),b)=\min(\max(Y,a),b)$ a.s. follows obviously from $X=c$ a.s. Is this correct?

Comment: "It is obvious that $Y$ is constant"? And what is the relation of the 2 with 1? Why they both ask you to prove $X=Y$ ?

Comment: @Andrew $Y=E[X]$, and $E[X]$ must be a constant?

Comment: I don't know how you got $Y=E[X]$ but it's not true

Comment: A conditional expectation is not constant in general. $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$ is constant in regard to $X$ but not straight up constant.

Comment: Ok it seems like $E[X|\mathcal F]$ is itself a random variable... But how can an expectation is not a number?

Comment: @Andrew Expectation is a number and a number is a constant I guess?

Comment: You might need to go back to how you defined conditional expectations. This is not a standard expectation, it is a random variable yes. You can see it as a generalisation of the usual expectation, if you will.

Comment: The conditional expectation is the expectation taken with respect to the random measure $\mu(\omega,\cdot)$ where $\mu$ is called the regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal F$. In the other words, the conditional expectation is an expectation, but since it is taken with respect to a random measure, it is a random variable.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428682/showing-that-x-sim-ex-mid-mathcalg-implies-x-ex-mid-mathcalg-almost?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in the comments, $\ Y\ $ is not necessarily constant.  By the definition of conditional expectations, however, it *is* $\ \mathcal{F}$-measurable, and so $\ E(YX|\mathcal{F})= YE(X|\mathcal{F})=Y^2\ $ almost surely.

If $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ have the same distribution and $\ X\ $ is square integrable, then so is $\ Y\ $, $\ E\big(Y^2\big)=E\big(X^2\big)\ ,$ and $\ XY\ $ is integrable, because the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) tells us that $\ E(|XY|)^2\le E\big(Y^2\big)E\big(X^2\big)\ $.

Therefore
\begin{align}
E\big((Y-X)^2\big)&=E\big(Y^2\big)-2E(YX)+E\big(X^2\big)\\
&=E\big(Y^2\big)-2E(E(YX|\mathcal{F}))+E\big(Y^2\big)\\
&=2E\big(Y^2\big)-2E\big(Y^2\big)\\
&=0\ ,
\end{align}
from which it follows that $\ Y=X\ $ almost surely.

Comment: For part2, we no longer need the "square integrable" to conclude that $X=Y$ a.s.?

Comment: That's correct, I believe.  I haven't completed a proof for part $2,$ but I'm guessing that you're supposed to apply part $1$ to the random variables $\ \tilde{X}_{a,b}\ed\min(\max(X,a),b)\ $ and $\ \tilde{Y}_{a,b}\ed$$\,\min(\max(Y,a),b)\ $. It's fairly obvious that $\ \tilde{X}_{a,b}\ $, and $\ \tilde{Y}_{a,b}\ $ have the same distribution and are square imtegrable. It's not so obvious (not, at least, to me) that $\ \tilde{Y}_{a,b}=E(\tilde{X}_{a,b}|\mathcal{F})\ $, but I think I can see how you might go about proving it.

Comment: Once you have $\ \tilde{Y}_{a,b}=\tilde{X}_{a,b}\ $ a.s. then $\ Y=X\ $ a.s. follows from the fact that $$\{Y=X\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\big\{\tilde{Y}_{-n,n}=\tilde{X}_{-n,n}\big\}\ . $$

Comment: You are a genius!